# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel' discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

My code:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, url: str = 'http://stream.radioparadise.com/rock-128'):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    global player
    try:
        player = await channel.connect()
    except:
        pass
    player.play(FFmpegPCMAudio('http://stream.radioparadise.com/rock-128'))
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'`
```

I try to make that the bot play a radio in the voice channel, but don't recognize the attribute channel. I'm using Zorin OS based on ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know discord.py, but this error means that `ctx.message.author.voice` returned None.

Answer (score 0):

Here `ctx.message.author.voice` is returning `None`, meaning the author is not connected to any voice channel. To solve this you need to check if `voice` returned None or not

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, url: str = 'http://stream.radioparadise.com/rock-128'):
    voice = ctx.message.author.voice
    if not voice:
        return await ctx.send("Author is not connected to any voice channel")
    channel = voice.channel
    global player
    try:
        player = await channel.connect()
    except:
        pass
    player.play(FFmpegPCMAudio('http://stream.radioparadise.com/rock-128'))
```